# Why can't we use the unit circle to get the value of sin x ,here?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I was solving this problem (this isn't a hw question I already have the answers)

> The acute angle *x* radiens is such that tan*x* = *k*, where *k* is a positive constant.

> Express, in terms of *k*,

> **i)** tan(*π* – *x*) **[*-k*]**

> **ii)** tan(1/2*π* – *x*) **[1/*k*]**

> **iii)** sin *x* **[*k*/√1+*k*^2]**

A friend told me that this question can't be solved with unit circle, because to use the ratio tan *x* = *k*/1
you will make y=k and x=1 so you will end up with a radius that's not equal to 1.

However, I didn't understand the problem with that since after all we're working with ratios and even if that radius is bigger or smaller than 1 using a circle to get the answer would still make the answer valid.

Anyway I solved i and ii using the unit circle then when it came to **(iii)** sin *x*, I wrote the answer to be k since sin is the value of the y coordinate but when I checked the answer it was k/√1+k^2 (by drawing a right angled triangle) and mine was wrong but I can't get my head around why it's wrong.

Update: one reason this was so confusing for me was because of a very big misconception I had, I thought that even if the radius gets to be, say, 2 the y coordinate will still be equal to sin *x* which isn't right, now sin *x* would be equal y/2.  I thought I should write this in case anyone had this misconception as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to explain.

Suppose $\tan x = k$. You can write $k$ as a fraction $\frac k1$.

You know $\tan x = \frac{\sin x }{\cos x}$, so you want to find the numerator (i.e., $\sin x$) of this fraction.

But of course, every fraction can be written in lots of ways: $\frac k1 =\frac{2k}2 = \frac{3k}3\cdots$, so which one is the right numerator to choose?

You want the one where the numerator and denominator are the $y$ and $x$ coordinates of a point on the unit circle, so you want $(\textrm{num})^2 + (\textrm{denom})^2 = 1$.

So you want to find $c$ such that for the fraction $\frac{ck}{c}$ you have $(ck)^2 + (c)^2 = 1$. You can solve this equation for $c$ as follows:
$$(ck)^2 + (c)^2 = 1$$
$$c^2k^2 + c^2=1$$
$$c^2(k^2+1)=1$$
$$c^2 = \frac 1{k^2+1}$$
$$c = \pm\frac1{\sqrt{k^2+1}}$$

So you want to choose the numerator of the fraction $\frac {ck}k$, i.e., $ck$. But since $c = \pm\frac1{\sqrt{k^2+1}}$, you have two possibilities:
$$\sin x = \pm \frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}$$

Now since $x$ is acute, you want to choose the positive version (so the point $(c,ck)$ is in the first quadrant). So finally, you arrive at

$$\sin x = \boxed{\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}}$$

---

**Long story short:**

If you know that $$\tan\theta = \frac ab$$ then you also know that
$$\sin\theta = \pm\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$$
$$\cos\theta = \pm\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$$
where the $\pm$ is chosen to be the same in both expressions (it's just because $\frac ab = \frac{-a}{-b}$).